# Use Javascript Bookmarklet to Chunk Page Content by Headings

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I've got an HTML page that is compiled dynamically from a database that I need to restyle and restructure. It looks messy, I know, but what I'm working with is this (note: no `<head>` or `<body>` tags):

```
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
...
```

I'm trying to code a javascript bookmarklet that will reformat and redivide the page into classed `<div>`'s so that I can restyle it. In other words, I need it to end up like this:

```
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<div class="one">
 <h1>Heading 1</h1>
 <p>Some paragraph</p>
 <p>Some paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="two">
 <h2>Heading 2</h2>
 <p>Some paragraph</p>
 <p>Some paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="three">
 <h3>Heading 3</h3>
 <p>Some paragraph</p>
 <p>Some paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="two">
 <h2>Heading 2</h2>
 <p>Some paragraph</p>
 <p>Some paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Please note that I can't do anything to the existing page; I have to do it through a bookmarklet or add-on.

Comment: "Please note that I can't do anything to the existing page" - what exactly do you mean with this? If you need to change the DOM you are going to alter the page somehow.

Comment: I just meant that I can't do anything server-side. It'll all have to be done client-side via the bookmarklet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jquery.  Just walk the childNode pseudo-array (presumably of the body...a body element should be created even if not specified in the html), and build an output array of elements.  When you hit a h1/h2/h3, you'll create a div, add it to the end of the array, as well as saving it as the "current element" which other elements will be added to.  Once done, you can add those elements to the body (or put them somewhere else).

```
var parent = document.body, i;
// copy into temp array, since otherwise you'll be walking
// an array (childnodes) whose size is changing as elements 
// get removed from it
var tmpArray = [];
for (i=0; i<parent.childNodes.length; i++)
 tmpArray.push(parent.childNodes[i]);

var tagToClassMap = {H1: "one", H2: "two", H3: "three"};
var newArray = [], currElem = null;
for (i=0; i<tmpArray.length; i++) {
  var elem = tmpArray[i];
  var className = null;
  if (elem.tagName && (className = tagToClassMap[elem.tagName]) != null) { 
    currElem = document.createElement("div");
    currElem.className = className;
    newArray.push(currElem);
    currElem.appendChild (elem);
    }
  else  {
    if (currElem)
      currElem.appendChild (elem);
    else 
      newArray.push(elem);
    } 
  }

parent.innerHTML = '';
for (i=0; i<newArray.length; i++) {
 parent.appendChild (newArray[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, this is wrapping each node in its own div and that isn't working for me.

Comment: I see you have a solution that works for you, however I'm surprised this one doesn't work as well. I tested it and it does what your example does....it only wraps each H1/H2/H3 element in a div, and then all subsequent elements are added to the last div created.  Any elements prior to the first H1/H2/H3 are added to the parent element.  (it's a little more "manual" than the jquery solution, but I prefer this way since its easier to follow what it is actually doing, in my opinion)

Comment: This actually works really well. Thanks. Any idea how to put all `class=three` `div`'s inside the previous `class=two` `div` and on up the chain, so that only the `class=one` `div`'s are at the top level?

Answer (score 0):

You could insert jQuery from the bookmarklet, and then it's rather easy:

```
function a() {
    var names = {'h1': 'one',
                 'h2': 'two',
                 'h3': 'three',
                 'h4': 'four',
                 'h5': 'five',
                 'h6': 'six'};
    var i = 1;
    jQuery('*').filter(":header").each(function() {
        jQuery(this)
        .add(jQuery(this)
            .nextUntil( jQuery("*")
                        .filter(":header")) )
            .wrapAll( jQuery("<div class='" + names[this.nodeName.toLowerCase()] + "'>") );
    });
};

(function(){
    var s=document.createElement('script');
    s.src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    s.onload = function(){
        setTimeout(a, 500);
    };
})();
```

Or, in one line:

```
javascript:function a(){var b={h1:"one",h2:"two",h3:"three",h4:"four",h5:"five",h6:"six"};jQuery("*").filter(":header").each(function(){jQuery(this).add(jQuery(this).nextUntil(jQuery("*").filter(":header"))).wrapAll(jQuery("<div class='"+b[this.nodeName.toLowerCase()]+"'>"))})}(function(){var b=document.createElement("script");b.src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js";document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(b);b.onload=function(){setTimeout(a,500)}})();
```

Comment: Thanks. That _almost_ works, but I need the class names to match the heading level. This just increases the class by 1 with each successive div. 

Does that make sense?

Comment: @damenleeturks: I'm sorry, I didn't quite see where the class names were coming from. I hope it's fixed now.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, it works fine. Followed up with a [question about how to tweak this a bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112509/use-javascript-bookmarklet-to-chunk-page-content-by-headings-part-2).