# Use Javascript Bookmarklet to Chunk Page Content by Headings (part 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I've some javascript that [@pimvdb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514749/pimvdb) helped me with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099536/use-javascript-bookmarklet-to-chunk-page-content-by-headings/), and I was wondering if it could be tweaked so that it would group lesser heading's `div`'s within the next higher's `div`.

In other words, start with this HTML:

```
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<p>Some paragraph</p>

<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<p>Some paragraph</p>

<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<p>Some paragraph</p>

<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<p>Some paragraph</p>

<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<p>Some paragraph</p>

<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
...
```

… and then use javascript (via a bookmarklet because it all has to be done client-side) to end up with this:

```
<div class="one">

  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <p>paragraph</p>

  <div class="two">
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>paragraph</p>

    <div class="three">
      <h3>Heading 3</h3>
      <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>

    <div class="three">
      <h3>Heading 3</h3>
      <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="one">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <p>paragraph</p>

  <div class="two">
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>paragraph</p>

    <div class="three">
      <h3>Heading 3</h3>
      <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your output html isn't valid, you don't close one of the divs.

Comment: Oops, thanks for catching that. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

How about just assigning classes to each different header instead of using :header, use each element type individualy and work from the highest to the lowest.

```
 function a() {

    $('h3').each(function() {
        $(this)
            .add($(this).nextUntil( $("h3")) ).wrapAll( $("<div class='three'>") );
    });

    $('h2').each(function() {
        $(this)
            .add($(this).nextUntil( $("h2")) ).wrapAll( $("<div class='two'>") );
    }); 


   $('h1').each(function() {
        $(this)
            .add($(this).nextUntil( $("h1")) ).wrapAll( $("<div class='one'>") );
    });


};
```

Comment: This is grabbing each group correctly, but it's double wrapping each element in identical `div`'s AND nesting everything inside each other almost endlessly. At an organizational level, all `class='one'` `div`'s should be at the top level and should contain all other classes that occur between that `h1` and the next `h1`.

Comment: Nevermind, it's not double-wrapping, I was accidentally calling the function twice. But it's still nesting every successive div created within the previous one, no matter what the level.

Answer (score 0):

Altered my answer to part one:

```
var parent = document.body, i;
var tmpArray = [];
for (i=0; i<parent.childNodes.length; i++)
 tmpArray.push(parent.childNodes[i]);


var headerArray = [];
var classNames = [null, "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

var newArray = [], currElem = null;

for (i=0; i<tmpArray.length; i++) {
  var elem = tmpArray[i];
  var tagData = null;
  var which;
  if (elem.tagName && 
      elem.tagName.charAt(0) == 'H' && 
      (which = parseInt(elem.tagName.charAt(1))) > 0) {  
    currElem = document.createElement("div");
    currElem.className = classNames[which];
    currElem.appendChild (elem);
    headerArray[which] = currElem;
    if (which > 1)
      headerArray[which-1].appendChild(currElem); 
    else
      newArray.push(currElem);
    }
  else  {
    if (currElem)
      currElem.appendChild (elem);
    else 
      newArray.push(elem);
    } 
  }

parent.innerHTML = '';
for (i=0; i<newArray.length; i++) {
 parent.appendChild (newArray[i]);
 }
```

Comment: It's not working for me. I'm getting an error on this line: `(which = parseInt(elem.tagName.charAt(1))) > 0) {`.

Comment: I edited it, i somehow had a "f" when it should have been "if".  Does that fix it?  I did test this, that error must have happened when I pasted it in or something....  If still doesn't work I'll test again and fix.

Comment: (one thing to note:  you didn't really define what would happen if there is an H3 but never an H2 (etc)....in my code, my answer is to have it crash. :)  You could wrap the whole thing with an exception handler, or special case that scenario, or just avoid that sort of input html...your choice! )