# How to give the option to download page as a complete HTML file (AFTER being reformatted and styled using JS/CSS)

Tags: php, javascript, html, download, save-as

I have a webpage that is generated by using PHP to pull fields from a database and set them in HTML.

Once this page loads, I use a combination of javascript ([which I asked about before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099536/use-javascript-bookmarklet-to-chunk-page-content-by-headings/6103700#6103700)) and CSS to reformat and style the page to be more legible.

What I need now is provide a way for the user to download the rendered page (after the javascript/css manipulates the page) as a whole HTML file.

And I'm coming up short. Can some one help?

Problems I'm encountering include:

- using "Save" or "Save as" dialogs in the browser save only the original HTML as pulled by the PHP. I end up having to "Inspect element" and copy the rendered HTML from the developer view.
- The CSS and JS that I'm adding are done on the client-side, and the PHP takes a little while to load (out of my hands). A solution to this question will need to be able to be done on either the client-side, or on a separate site/server.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a server side proxy on your own server (eg. [PHP Web Proxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-proxy/)) which grabs the unformatted html page in question from the source server, reformats it on your server, and then sends it to the browser in the state you want to save.

Answer (score 0):

I never had the need to save it as a file but for troubleshooting it is cumbersome when you don's see the complete rendered page, especially with Jscripts. "Inspect element" is the only solution I have used so far to see rendered page.

There is also a tool called [crowbar](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Crowbar) which I have never really tried because for troubleshooting purposes "Inspect element" was all I ever needed.

I am not sure what you want with CSS. Styles are visual element which cannot really be saved.